# How does Yarn resolve Git dependencies?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Yarn (and NPM) allow you to specify Git dependencies like this:

```
yarn add <git remote url>
```

or

```
yarn add <git remote url>#<branch/commit/tag>
```

(Taken from [the docs](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/))

This is easy to understand in simple cases, where you have one Git dependency and there are no transitive dependencies, but it is not always clear how this works with more complex dependency graphs.

**Example 1**

`package.json`

```
... 
"dependencies": {
  "package-b1": "git@github.com:user/package-b.git"`, 
  "package-b2": "git@github.com:user/package-b.git"`
}
```

Will Yarn spot that `package-b1` and `package-b2` have the same Git URL? Will they always resolve to the same commit-hash?

**Example 2**

`package.json`

```
... 
"dependencies": {
  "package-b": "git@github.com:user/package-b.git"`, 
  "package-c": "git@github.com:user/package-c.git"`
}
```

`github.com/user/package-b/package.json`

```
... 
"dependencies": {
  "package-c": "git@github.com:user/package-c.git"`
}
```

Will Yarn spot that our package and `package-b` both depend on the same Git URL? Will they be resolved to the same hash?

**Example 3**

`package.json`

```
... 
"dependencies": {
  "package-b": "git@github.com:user/package-b.git"`, 
  "package-c1": "git@github.com:user/package-c.git"`
}
```

`github.com/user/package-b/package.json`

```
... 
"dependencies": {
  "package-c2": "git@github.com:user/package-c.git"`
}
```

This example is the same, but `git@github.com:user/package-c.git` has two different names. Are they considered different dependencies?

**Example 4**

`package.json`

```
... 
"dependencies": {
  "package-b": "git@github.com:user/package-b.git"`, 
  "package-c": "git@github.com:user/package-c.git"`
}
```

`github.com/user/package-b/package.json`

```
... 
"dependencies": {
  "package-c": "git@github.com:user/package-c-2.git"`
}
```

This example is also similar, but now there are two packages with the same name but different URLs. What will Yarn do here?

**Summary**

I'm sure I could think of more examples. Can someone shed some light on how this stuff is meant to work?

Things get *even more complicated* when you realise that each commit-hash might have a different `package.json`. Will Yarn try different commits if some contain dependency conflicts?